# how to create inner list for a given list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a program to get two-piece of information and put them on a list. I want each part to be in an inner list. For example:
list=[[student_number1,average1],[student_number2,average2],.......]
but I cannot organize them as a list.

```
#new_list=[]
while True:
student_number=input('please enter your student number:')
if student_number=="done":
        break
average=input('please enter you average:')
if student_number=="done":
        break
new_list=new_list.append([student_number,average])
print(new_list)
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\hosna\programming\python\mypro.py", line 271, in <module>
    
new_list=new_list.append([student_number,average])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
new_list=new_list.append([student_number,average])
```

You're assigning value new_list to the return value from the append function, which is `None`. To append to a list, you don't need to make an assignment. Change this line to:

```
new_list.append([student_number,average])
```

Additionally, the term you're linking for "inner list" is *nested list*

Here's your fixed code:

```
new_list=[]
while True:
    student_number=input('please enter your student number:')
    if student_number=="done":
            break
    average=input('please enter you average:')
    if average=="done":
            break
    new_list.append([student_number,average])
    print(new_list)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,i tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work!!

Comment: Can you explain why this fix doesn't work? I have it working on my end. I went ahead and put your code with this fix above. I've also been able to replicate your described output using it: [['student1', 'average1'], ['student2', 'average2']]